# Triangles Numbers counting

Tags: geometry

[image]

How measure to number of triangles??? any helps??

I want to calculate it  by  using a formula.

Comment: Is that tiny triangle towards the bottom left supposed to be there?

Comment: __Hint:__ Tabulate $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ and you should have enough information to guess at the pattern. Then you can prove it by induction, or by creating a nice bijection.

Answer (score 1):

My answer has mathematics and observation.

My approach is to get the number of triangles of a paricular size, and then add that to the next size, and so on.

First, as your figure has four small triangles on each side, I take *t* as $4$. But that comes later.

---

Starting with triangles of Size $1$. The number of Size $1$ is $1$ on the top row, $3$ on the second, $5$ on the third, and so on. In fact, it starts with $1$ and goes in an Arithmetic Progression of common difference $2$. This makes it the series of odd numbers from $1$.

As we all know, the sum of all odd numbers from $1^st$ to $n^{th}$ is $n^2$. That is, $1+3+5+7+...+(2n-1) = n^2$

And since that is what we have here,

> The number of triangles of Size $1$ is $t^2$.

---

Onto Size $2$. You will see that the triangles of Size $2$ begin at the second line from the top. In fact, for this kind of figures, triangles of size $a$ will begin at the $a^{th}$ line from the top. If we see here, there is $1$ such triangle on the second line, $2$ on the third line, and so on. But here, it continues only until $(t-1)$.

As we know, $1+2+3+4+...+n = {{n(n+1)}\over2}$. Here, $n$ is $(t-1)$. So, it is changed to $(t-1)\{(t-1)+1\}\over2$, on simplifying which we get $t(t-1)\over2$. So,

> The number of triangles of Size $2$ is $t(t-1)\over2$.

---

For Size $3$, the triangles will start from the third from top, and continue from $1$ till $(t-2)$. Going by the same method applied above, we get that

> The number of triangles of Size $3$ is $(t-1)(t-2)\over2$.

---

### Taking into account upside down triangles of sizes $2$ and above in figures of sizes $4$ and above gets us ${\sum_{n=4}^{t}{2(n-4)}}+1$

This goes on and on, so the final formula for total number of triangles $n$ in a figure of side $t$ is:-

> > > > > $$\small{n=t^2+{{t(t-1)}\over{2}}+{{(t-1)(t-2)}\over2}+{{(t-2)(t-3)}\over2}+{\cdots}+{{1×0}\over2}+\{\sum_{n=4}^{t}{2(n-4)\}}+1}$$

Which can also be written as:-

> > > > > $$t^2+{{\sum_{n=0}^{t-1} {(t-n)(\{t-(n+1)\}\over2}}}+{\{{\sum_{n=4}^{t}{2(n-4)}}\}+1}$$

Comment: You are missing out a lot of "upside down" triangles (which is also why the formula is so different for the size 1 case). IE There are (t+1)*t/2 "right side up, size 1" triangles. There are t*(t-1)/2 "upside down, size 1" triangles.

Comment: I am not, actually. If you try it for sizes, say 2 or 3 or so on, you will find that they are included

Comment: @CalvinLin I am not, actually. If you try it for figures with t as say 2 or 3, or so on, you will find that it holds.

Comment: For size 2 and 3, there is no "upside down size 2 triangle" hence your answer remains numerically correct. For size 4, you are missing the 1 "upside down size 2 triangle".

Comment: @CalvinLin I am not, actually. If you try it for sizes, say 2 or 3 or so on, you will find that they are included. It holds for any t which is a natural number

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh, I see what you meant, now. Sorry for that pointless argument.